# Vb.net receives the directory list in the specific directory and saves it in a file.txt

Tags: vb.net, list, text, directory

**I need to create a list of existing directory names in a specific folder**

```html
Dim WorksList As String = Application.StartupPath + "\db\works.txt"
SlcTextBox_BaseWorksDirectory = "c:\ListDirectory"

If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(SlcTextBox_BaseWorksDirectory.Text) Then
Saves all existing directory names SlcTextBox_BaseWorksDirectory.text (c:\ListDirectory) in a WorksList (works.txt)
End If
```

**File works.txt**

ADirectory1
BDirectory2
CDirectory3
DDirectory4
EDirectory5
FDirectory6
GDirectory7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the existing directories of a specific directory to a file, simply retrieve the files using `GetDirectories` and print using `AppendAllLines`. You can replace `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments` with the path to the directory you want to list.

```
    Dim directories = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)

    IO.File.AppendAllLines(WorksList, directories.Select(Function(f) f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)))
```

This assumes a WorksList points to a valid existing text file.

Comment: Hi @mike100111 Thank you for your answer !

The result with your code is this
C:\Users\Michel\Desktop\Testing\namedicrectory4


I instead expect this
namedicrectory4

Comment: View my edit. It uses linq to trim off everything before final directory name.